# Performance of CSS Flex vs. manual JavaScript computation

Tags: javascript, css, performance, web, flexbox

I have a browser-based system which consists of, among other modular components, an `<iframe>` container which is nested with other `<iframe>` for - currently - up to three levels. A given webpage may be embedded within multiple nested frames simultaneously. The end-users' screen resolutions and the nested frames' sizes can vary.

It is therefore important for element sizes, paddings, margins etc. to be defined in relative terms. To this end, I have identified two approaches: Either I use CSS Flex wherever possible and compute with JavaScript manually for the rest, or do the reverse and compute wherever possible. Here's an example of the computation-focused approach for one of my more complex pages to be embedded in the frames:

```
// Tile size-dependent CSS
const RATIO = 0.618;

// Amount of space to use in view
var viewHeight = window.innerHeight;
var viewWidth = window.innerWidth;
var viewVertSpace = viewHeight * 0.8;
var viewHoriSpace = viewWidth * 0.8;

// Position and sizing for each overall column
var colWidth = Math.round(viewHoriSpace * 0.5);
var colSpace = Math.round(viewVertSpace) - 2; // Deduct 2px bottom border

// Sizing of column 1 elements
var summaryHeight = colSpace * 0.5;
var mainRowHeight = summaryHeight * RATIO;
var mainRowSize = Math.round(mainRowHeight - 10); // Deduct 5px vertical padding per side
var subTextSize = Math.round((summaryHeight - mainRowHeight) * (1 - RATIO));
var diffIconSize = Math.round((mainRowSize - subTextSize) * RATIO);

// Sizing of column 2 elements
var horiSpace = colWidth * RATIO; // Leave some space on both sides
var chartWidth = horiSpace - (horiSpace * RATIO);
var innerBarWidth = chartWidth * (1 - RATIO);
var targetArrowWidth = subTextSize * 0.5;
```

There is a performance constraint on the system's loading time, one which has been failed during the first deployment to the test server. I have been continuously optimising the code (part of which involved implementing lazy initialisation and ordered loading to prevent too many simultaneous HTTP calls) and this is one area I'm looking at. I have read that extensive use of CSS Flex in more complex applications can have a significant performance impact but I wonder if relying on manual computation via JavaScript to set absolute pixel sizes is actually better?

Comment: Lol iframe within iframe within iframe. Thats your problem. At the very least CSS computation are not DOM blocking as some JS are.

Comment: @WilomGfx Well I have already addressed the loading impact of nested iframes so that is no longer an issue at this point. The next issue is regarding the calculation of sizes for each frame's content. The intuitive approach is to use CSS, and Flex is designed for things like these but lots of Flex can drag the loading down too. Will switching to JavaScript computation help?

Comment: There is no general answer to this question. It depends on the browser, your implementation, when and how often you compute and apply these size changes, render cycles, accessing dom nodes (or their properties), etc. etc. It boils down to: show me an implementation and *the actual page* this is running on, and I can tell you wether/how you can do better. The best (general) hint I can give you is to avoid *unnecessary* render cycles as much as possible.

Comment: I voted to close, as this question is either too broad or primarily opinion-based. If you want to keep it open, make it much more specific.

Answer (score 0):

While specific implementations may vary, here are some general things to consider:

You will not be able to control when the CSS causes your elements to resize, with JavaScript, you can make some decisions such as setting timeouts or establishing minimum values to trigger a change. However, any such solutions will be blocking any other JavaScript you may wish to be running in the same time frame. Similarly, any other JavaScript you have running will block this code. Using CSS Flexbox will require you to check on which browser-specific implementation details apply to your use cases (the same is of course true in your JavaScript).

In my experience, CSS flexbox has been faster than any JavaScript solutions that attempt to address the same concerns, I cannot guarantee that this is a universal truth though.

You should also consider code maintenance when implementing a solution. If your JavaScript is full of magic numbers and strange conditionals, it might be easier to maintain a CSS solution (assuming you do not fill it with magic numbers and strange conditionals as well, which I find easier to avoid with a Flexbox).

**I'm sorry I can't give you a "use this every time answer", but hopefully this will help you make good decisions given the constrains that exist**